# VBA is my object deleted if I set it to a new one

Tags: vba, pointers

```
While Not code_Download = 0     'code_Download = 0 --> CORRECT
    If delay < 30000 Then       
        delay = delay + 2000
    Else
        MsgBox "Delay too long"
        CREATEtemp_fileXML = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium ' <<<<<<<<<
    IE.Navigate wURL
    Sleep delay
    IE.Quit
    code_Download = URLDownloadToFile(0, wURL, temp_fileXML, 0, 0)
```

So I set a new InternetExplorermedium everytime I pass in the loop. Without that I get an error of not recognized interface. I was wondering if I can and How to destroy previous pointers or if this is "not so bad" practice.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not so bad in VBA. You can do a `Set IE = Nothing` after your `IE.Quit` if you want to completely eradicate any reference that was left before the next iteration. I don't believe it will make much difference in this case since IE.Quit should send the object into oblivion anyway.